# Is it possible to make a bossbar in Java Edition 1.12 or below?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to add a bossbar to one of the boss mobs in my map. But I'm working in 1.12.2.

1.13 has a `/bossbar` command, but this is a later version than the one I am working in. How can I make my custom bossbar in 1.12?

Answer (score 2):

Bossbars did not exist in 1.12−. What you have to do is (ab)use an existing mob that already has built-in bossbar.

You can use the Wither if you want a red bossbar, or the Ender Dragon if you want a purple bossbar. Unfortunately those are the only colours you may select.

You can add the tags `{NoAI: 1b, Silent: 1b}` to stop your mob from disturbing your gameplay.

Comment: That is true since /entitydata existed in that version. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can’t use bossbars in that version. The best you can do is summon a Wither and rename it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do bossbars with color codes, but with a command which you need to place and then activate, the command is:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ standing_sign 0 replace {Text1: "{\"text\":\"Rechtsklick!\"}",Text2: "{\"text\":\"\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:\\\"say \\u00A7aTest\\u00A7cTest\\u00A77Test\\\"}\"}}"}
```

In the command it will then show "§", but it will be invisible.
In 1.12.2 you can use that command to rename the Wither and make it a colourful bossbar, but you can't change the bossbar color itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a wither and rename it with a nametag and a anvil, it should work.

I also suggest you do it under ground in a bedrock box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And it doesn't differ too much from other answers.